# Setting and displaying an error for a custom validation with client side code

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

I have a custom field validator that fires some client side code to validate the value of a text box. If the value is invalid, I would like to display a message in the custom validatior. I am able to assign the value to the validator but when it loads on the page it is set to visibility = hidden or display = none. I have tried setting both properties to visible on the client side and in the validator.

Client side:

```
 if (data.d == null) {
                    sender.errormessage = $('#<%= txtHaulerNumber.ClientID %>').val() + " is not a valid Hauler Number.";
                    sender.innerHTML = $('#<%= txtHaulerNumber.ClientID %>').val() + " is not a valid Hauler Number.";
                    sender.text = $('#<%= txtHaulerNumber.ClientID %>').val() + " is not a valid Hauler Number.";
                    $('#<%= cfvHaulerNumber.ClientID %>').visible = true;
                    args.IsValid = false;
                    $('#<%= txtHaulerNumber.ClientID %>').focus();
                }
```

ASP validator

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cfvHaulerNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtHaulerNumber" 
            ErrorMessage="" onservervalidate="cfvHaulerNumber_ServerValidate"
            ValidateEmptyText="true" ClientValidationFunction = "GetHauler" EnableClientScript = "true" 
            Visible = "true" Display = "Static"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

UPDATE:
I am positive that the method is running as it reformats the text I enter into the text box. When I open Firebug and look at the HTML, I can find the error message is being assigned to the validator, but something is forcing it to be hidden.

```
<span style="color: Red; visibility: hidden;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cfvHaulerNumber"></span>
```

How can I force this to be visible?

Comment: The message will appear when you try to post an invalid value. It will happen client side if javascript is enabled.

Comment: Are you sure your GetHauler method is executed? Try setting some alerts in the function for debugging and check what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I ran few tests and it seems to be CustomValidator Not working in FireFox with ASP.NET 4.0. It works fine in IE. It works fine in FF with .NET 2.0.

I did some search and seems it was an issue with Validators with 1.1 which was resolved in 2.0. Wondering there is some other setting are needed in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Late response but,
validator will only go hidden if its **IsValid** property is set to **True**.

You might want to check and adjust your javascript accordingly.